# Jest test is timing out - why?

Tags: javascript, https, jestjs

I have create a javascript function that works stand-alone, yet fails when testing via Jest. Im not sure why...

[CODE GITHUB](https://github.com/michaelbev/codeChallenges/tree/main/node)

```
 FAIL  node/FileParseHashChallenge.test.js
  ● FileParseHashChallenge

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "0bX78Xa3X9eXe8Xf9Xc4X9bX60X09X00X38XbaX9xXfiXmcX"
    Received: undefined

       7 |
       8 | test('FileParseHashChallenge', async () => {
    >  9 |   expect(await FileParseHashChallenge()).toBe('0bX78Xa3X9eXe8Xf9Xc4X9bX60X09X00X38XbaX9xXfiXmcX')
         |
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
> npm test

Test Suites: 1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Tests:       1 failed, 6 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.736 s, estimated 1 s
```

Expected all tests to pass

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Wrap that http.get() call into a promise and resolve with the hash string when successful. I'm not sure if the syntax of an async jest test is correct, but this would be the first step.

Comment: return finalHex

Comment: Fixed this issue by adding a promise to control flow

Comment: Fixed this issue by adding a promise to control flow